# Vlookup equivalent with Pandas for multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following Excel file (Sheet1):

| Origin City | Destination City |
| --- | --- |
| New York | Berlin |
| Los Angeles | London |
| Houston | Miami |
| San Francisco | Newark |

And the second sheet (Sheet2) with the code to each city:

| City | Code |
| --- | --- |
| New York | NYC |
| Los Angeles | LA |
| Houston | HOU |
| San Francisco | SF |
| Berlin | BER |
| London | LON |
| Miami | MIA |
| Newark | NWK |

I want the following:

| Origin City | Origin Code | Destination City | Destination Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | NYC | Berlin | BER |
| Los Angeles | LA | London | LON |
| Houston | HOU | Miami | MIA |
| San Francisco | SF | Newark | NWK |

I am using the following code but am getting "NaN"

```
df_Main_File = pd.read_excel(Main_File, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_City_Name = pd.read_excel(Main_File, sheet_name='Sheet2')

df_Merge = pd.merge(df_Main_File,df_City_Name, on = ['Origin City','Destination City'], how = 'left')

print(df_Merge)
```

Comment: Umm... do you really want two columns with the same name?

Comment: I changed it to "Origin Code" and "Destination Code"

Answer (score 1):

```
df_result = (df_Main_File.reset_index().melt('index', value_name='City').
              merge(df_City_Name).pivot('index', 'variable'))

df_result.columns = df_result.columns.map(lambda x: x[1].replace('City', x[0]))

df_result.sort_index(axis = 1, ascending = False)
 
      Origin Code    Origin City Destination Code Destination City
index                                                             
1             NYC       New York              BER           Berlin
2              LA    Los Angeles              LON           London
3             HOU        Houston              MIA            Miami
4              SF  San Francisco              NWK           Newark
```

Comment: KeyError: 'Origin City'

Comment: @DavidWooley-AST I never used any key. I just used `melt` + `merge` + `pivot`